# Using react-rnd with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm using **react-rnd** and want to use it with a hooks component. From the example in the docs I don't understand how to implement it. With a class component I can just copy the example:

```
<Rnd
  size={{ width: this.state.width,  height: this.state.height }}
  position={{ x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y }}
  onDragStop={(e, d) => { this.setState({ x: d.x, y: d.y }) }}
  onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
    this.setState({
      width: ref.style.width,
      height: ref.style.height,
      ...position,
    });
  }}
>
  001
</Rnd>
```

I don't understand what's happening with `...position` in the `onResizeStop` prop.

Can anyone help me out with understanding what `...position` is doing and how to turn this into a hook component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work or at least give you an idea:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0});

<Rnd
  size={{ width: state.width,  height: state.height }}
  position={{ x: state.x, y: state.y }}
  onDragStop={(e, d) => { setState({...state, x: d.x, y: d.y}) }}
  onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
    setState({
        width: ref.style.width, 
        height: ref.style.height,
        ...position
    })
  }}
>
  001
</Rnd>
```

You can replace the part with `...position` with:

```
setState({
    width: ref.style.width, 
    height: ref.style.height,
    x: position.x,
    y: position.y 
});
```

It's the same :)

Comment: Thanks. The `{{ state.width,  state.height }}` syntax doesn't work for me. I've changed to `{{ width: state.width, height: state.height }}`. I didn't realise `position` is just an object that is being destructured.

Comment: Yea you are right! I edited the post accordingly. Glad it worked.